# TypeError: crop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop

```
from PIL import Image
img=Image.open('/home/ahmed/internship/cnn_ocr/image1.png')
img.size
(2458, 3504)
```

But when l try to crop the image as follow :

```
img.crop(414,122,650,338)
```

l got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: crop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

But `crop()` takes 4 parameter : left, top, right, bottom. What's wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No `crop` **takes one *explicit* parameter**: a 4-tuple (and implicitly of course the `self`). The [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) states:

> **`Image.crop(box=None)`**
>
> Returns a rectangular region from this image. The **`box` is a 4-tuple**
>   defining the *left*, *upper*, *right*, and *lower* pixel coordinate.
>
> **Note:** Prior to Pillow 3.4.0, this was a lazy operation.
>
> **Parameters:**
>      `box` - The crop rectangle, as a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple.
>   **Return type:** Image
>   **Returns:** An Image object.

(formatting added)

So you should rewrite it to:

```
img.crop((414,122,650,338))
#        ^    4-tuple    ^
```

Furthermore you better **assign the output** to a variable (possibly `img` itself):

```
some_other_img = img.crop((414,122,650,338))
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But it doesn't crop the image after making  img.crop((414,122,650,338)) , l tried img.size it gives me the original size of the image and with img.save('cropped_image.png') l get the original image

Comment: @vincent: see note below: the crop does not work inline: you need to assign the result (perhaps you can set it to `img`, so `img = img.crop(..)`).

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a same error.

> ```
> x = 0
> y = 0
>
> w = 1000/3
> h = 667/10
>
> mac.crop(x,y,w,h)
> ```

**TypeError: crop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given**

After, i tried below code get an output

> ```
> mac.crop((x,y,w,h))
> ```

Make sure you are try again, below mentioned code to get a clear result.

> ```
> img.crop((414,122,650,338))
> ```